# git-svn dcommit fails on directory with umlauts

Tags: svn, git, character-encoding, git-svn

## My Setup

I'm working on Windows XP 32bit (german). I installed

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.4.msysgit.0
```

and created a git-svn repository where I successfully commited a bunch of files and directories from a previous SCM.

## The Problem

But on the 2nd **git-svn dcommit** I got this error:

```
$ git svn dcommit
Committing to http://mysvnserver/repos/myrepo/trunk ...
RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/repos/myrepo/trunk/path/with/weird/%DC%20f%FC%20umlauts': \
 PROPFIND of '/repos/myrepo/trunk/path/with/weird/%DC%20f%FC%20umlauts': 207 Multi-Status (http://mysvnserver) at C:\Programme\Git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 4529
```

The directory has *german umlauts* in its name and I think the problem is a wrong conversion between **msysgit**, **svn** and **windows**. I can not delete the directory directly in the svn repository browser of **TortoiseSVN** nor can I check out the directory on **cygwin** because the directory is missing at all there.

I'm now stuck with a broken directory in SVN and can not **git-svn dcommit** the deletion of the directory because I then get the **RA layer request failed** error.

## My Question

Any tips? Do I have to clone the whole repository from SVN again?

Answer (score 0):

## The quick solution

I was able to remove the parent folder with the repository browser of **TortoiseSVN**. That fixed it for me.